# Manipulating a Hierarchical Dataset with Pandas and Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have set of restaurant sales data the structure of which comprises two dimensions: a location dimension and a food type dimension, as well as a fact table that contains some measures. I am having trouble manipulating the table to perform analysis. In the end, it will likely be displayed in excel.

Here is a toy dataset:

```
tuples = [('California', 'SF'), ('California', 'SD'),
         ('New York', 'Roch'), ('New York', 'NY'),
         ('Texas', 'Houst'), ('Texas', 'SA')]
measure1 =   [5, 10,
               30, 60,
               10, 30]
measure2   =   [50, 10,
               30, 6,
               1, 30]
tier1 = ['Burger',
         'Burger',
         'Burger',
         'Pizza',
         'Pizza',
         'Burger']
tier2 = ['Beef',
         'Chicken',
         'Beef',
         'Pep',
         'Cheese',
         'Beef']
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['State', 'City'])
revenue = pd.Series(measure1, index=index)
revenue = revenue.reindex(index)
rev_df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':tier1,
                       'Subcategory':tier2,
                       'Revenue': revenue,
                       'NumOfOrders': [3, 5,1, 3,10, 20]})
rev_df
```

This code produces this dataframe:

[image]

I want to do two things:

1. Place the Category and Subcategory as MultiIndex column headers and calculate NumOrder weighted revenue by food subcategory and category with subtotals and grand totals
2. Place the cities dimension on the Y-axis and move the Category and Subcategory by measure to the x-axis.

For example-
(1)

```
                    Burger            Total Burger  Pizza....
                    Beef     Chicken
      California SF  4         5         9
                 SD  5         5        10
      Total Califor  9         10       19
```

(2)

```
                     California         California Total
                        SF        SD 
Total Burger WgtRev      9        10        19
      Beef   WgtRev      4         5        10
      Chickn WgtRev      5         5        10
Total Pizza...
```

To start, my first attempt was to use a pivot_table

```
pivoted = rev_df.pivot_table(index = ['State','City'],
                      columns = ['Category','Subcategory'],
                     aggfunc = 'sum', #How to make it a weighted average?
                     margins = True, #How to subtotal and grandtotal?
                     margins_name = 'All',
                     fill_value = 0)
KeyError: "['State' 'City'] not in index"
```

As you can see, I get an error. What is the most python way to manipulate this snowflake-esque datamodel?

Comment: the problem here is that State and City are the index names, a quick fix would be to reset_index before the pivot, try `rev_df.reset_index().pivot...`, that said you might get a better solution to it

Comment: How do you get the `4` in the first cell of example (1) ? I assume it hast something to do with your definition of "weighted revenue", but can't find how it is computing

Comment: Forgive me, they are toy numbers. I’d like to weight the revenue by numOrders- sumproduct(rev, numOrders)/sum(numOrders)